# A closed and bounded set in an infinite-dimensional Space is not compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

I have a problem showing the following:

> Let $A:=\{\phi_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R},x\rightarrow x^n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ in $C^0([0,1])$ with the $||\cdot||_\infty$-norm. Show that $A$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

I already showed that $A$ is bounded and closed, but I need to find a sequence of functions in $A$ $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, so that for $a\neq b$: $||f_a-f_b||_\infty>c$ for a constant $c$. I looked through some examples, but they didn't help me to find this sequence.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The sequence $\phi_n$ has no convergence sub-sequence.

Comment: Because every sub-sequence of $\phi_n$ convergence point-wise to a non-continuous function hence cannot converge uniformly. (Should I write down the details?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that a sequence $(\phi_{n})$ of $A$ has a subsequence $(\phi_{n_{k}})$ converges to a $\phi\in A$, say, $\phi:x\rightarrow x^{n}$. Then there is some $N$ such that $|x^{n_{k}}-x^{n}|=|\phi_{n_{k}}(x)-\phi(x)|\leq\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\phi_{n_{k}}(x)-\phi(x)|=\|\phi_{n_{k}}-\phi\|_{\infty}<1/2$ for all $k\geq N$ and $x\in[0,1]$. Fix an $x\in[0,1)$, and take $k\rightarrow\infty$ we have $|x^{n}|\leq 1/2$. Now taking $x\rightarrow 1^{-}$ we have $1\leq 1/2$, a contradiction.